# get the folder name that is listed at last when the folders are ordered by name - batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, filenames

Please help me in getting the name of the folder from a list of folders(which are contained in one folder) that is present at last if the folders are arranged by name (i.e., in alphabetical order)

for example, if a folder named "stack" has a set of folders named a,b,c,d,e,f. Then the batch file should return me the name of the folder "f"

I have to do this in batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not the most elegant method.
I dir just folder names in revers sorted order and take the first item, then break. This avoids iterate through the whole list.
Script should have your folder as work directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /AD /B /O-N') do (
    set lastvalue=%%a
    goto break
)
:break
echo !lastvalue!
```

Answer (score 0):

The batch-file line you'd need would be

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /on stack') do set returnvalue=%%a
```

Then you'd display the return value

```
echo last name in directory is %returnvalue%
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using a temp file:
I dir folder names in revers sorted order and redirect to temp file. then I read once from that file and set the lastvalue value.

```
(dir /AD /B /O-N >temp.txt) && 5<temp.txt ( set /p lastvalue=<&5)
echo %lastvalue%
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add options. From command line (or change `%` to `%%` to use in batch file)

```
@for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %a in ('dir /b/o-n^|findstr /n "^"^|findstr "^1:"') do @echo %b
```